# HTML class refuses to look in CSS file

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use a class called "secondary" in my HTML file and set it's properties in my CSS file, but it seems like

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> My Webpage</title>
        <link href="D:\Web_developing\css\styles.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Main webpage</h1>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="D:\Web_developing\html\page2.html">page 2</a></li>
        </ul>

        <p class="secondary">this is the main page of the website</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    color: green;
    background: black;
    font-family: arial;
    text: white:
}
.secondary {
    background: green;
    color: blue
}
```

I expected the paragraph given the class would have the properties set in the CSS file.

---

After some testing with the file path I have concluded that the problem seems to be with the class. Is there perhaps any wrong syntax?

Comment: Are you only developing on localhost? It seems strange you have the `D:` in your path, and I am very sure this is your issue. Even when developing only locally, paths are relative to your working directory. In any case right click the page and view source, then you can manually load the CSS page by clicking the link from the source. If this CSS doesn't load when you click, you have found your issue, your webpage is returning a 404 error because the file isn't found. If this is the issue alter your path like so (assuming you are in the root directory) `Web_developing\css\styles.css`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The path given in the code, as far as I understand, should not be a problem since it finds the properties set for <body>.

Comment: Is the CSS exactly as in your actual site? The last style in the body in your quoted code ends with : instead of ; which is an error.

Comment: @StevePugh I have changed it and it made no difference, but thanks for poiting it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be with your link to the CSS file. It's always better to use relative paths when linking asset files to your web page. Try this instead...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css"/>
```

[Learn more about file paths here - W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html_filepaths.asp)

Comment: Now it acknowledges that there is something more than just the <body> properties but it still won't apply the .secondary properties.

Comment: What is the output you get? I checked the exact same code in my PC and its working perfectly. Try Ctrl + F5 to force refresh the page and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

If it is taking only the `<body>` property, try the `<div>` block and set the class for div, not a paragraph like `"<div class = " " ...>"`.

Otherwise, it will take `"<body>"` CSS properties.

Answer (score 0):

Your path does not appear to be correct for the CSS file, your code appears fine other than that.

Assuming you are inside the directory `Web_developing` change your CSS path to this:

```
<head>
    <title> My Webpage</title>
    <link href="css\styles.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
```

If your root directory has the directory `Web_developing` then change it to this:

```
<head>
    <title> My Webpage</title>
    <link href="Web_developing\css\styles.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
```

Comment: If i use any of those two options it doesn't find the css file.

Comment: @Moltas, have you figured this out yet? My relative paths were based on what I assumed you set your directory structure up to mimic. Let me know where you are storing your `styles.css` file relative to `index.html`, and I can give you the code to load it in your html page.